# Redundancy of words

Tags: grammar

- I always have doubts about sentences such as:

  > The subway is not so far **from the restaurant and from the hotel** where I decided to stay for a couple of days.
- Is it feasible to write instead:

  > The subway is not so far **from the restaurant and the hotel** where I decided to stay for a couple of days.
- What about:

  > The subway is not so far **from restaurant and hotel** where I decided to stay for a couple of days.

Answer (score 3):

Grammatically, you can do this. With one exception: you cannot drop the article "the" from both words. A single "the" will distribute over both:

> The subway is not so far from (((*the* (restaurant and hotel)) where I decided to stay) for a couple of days).

Don't put in the parentheses: they are my annotation.  Its purpose is to show the semantic problem. The sentence implies that the restaurant and hotel are a unit. There is a single distance from the restaurant-plus-hotel combo to the subway. Moreover, your sentence says that you stayed in the restaurant-plus-hotel combo for a few days.

The original sentence does not imply that the hotel and the restaurant are the same building. Its structure is roughly like this:

> The subway is not so far (from the restaurant) and (from the (hotel where I decided to stay for a couple of days)).
>
> [ The subway is not so far from the restaurant. It is also not so far from the hotel where I decided to stay for a couple of days. ]

If we distribute the article *the*, it helps to at least clear up that you did not stay in the restaurant and hotel, but just in the hotel. The interpretation also now steers toward that of the original sentence: that the restaurant and hotel are separate.

> The subway is not so far from (*the* restaurant) and (((*the* hotel) where I decided to stay) for a couple of days).

This actually illustrates an important syntactic/semantic power of English articles that doesn't seem to receive a lot of attention.

Answer (score 0):

**The subway is not too from either the restaurant or the hotel, that I stayed at for a couple of days.**

Not so sure about brevity, but this makes it a little less ambiguous and better structured.